No hang when stepping manually through problematic code; otherwise, it hangs. What tools does the editor + debugger have to examine?
I have a problematic section of code. The start of the section is decorated with a print statement, as is the end:
print("starting problematic section") # <-- breakpoint set here 
# various calls # <--- program hangs somewhere here if not manually stepping through
print("done.") # <-- breakpoint set here

When I use the debugger to step through the code manually everything works okay, and I hit both starting and ending print statements.
When I remove the breakpoint, and do not step through the code manually: program execution hangs. Therefore, it seems relevant to me to be able to see where the program is currently in execution, independently of any breakpoints I might have set.
How can I do so?
I have two ideas:

Can the editor continuously and automatically jump me to whatever point in the source is relevant corresponds to where the program currently is in its execution? (Note: this would be happening without any breakpoints being set, or any manual stepping through.)

Is it possible to examine a live-updating trace/call-stack of the program's execution?


(A unfeasible idea I considered: setting a "logpoint" on every single line of source code, which prints out the file/line of the breakpoint. Obviously, setting a logpoint on every line in every file is not possible since it would be awfully time consuming. But, the idea illustrates what I wish I could do: finding out where my program is stuck, when breakpoints/print-statements are not enough.)

Could be a timing issue, where your program need to wait for data somewhere, but in a normal running program it doesn't wait long enough. When you then use a debugger it takes much longer for you to step through the code, so the timing is not an issue for that case. Generally, running in a debugger is going to slow down the program, and it's less likely to be a problem with the debugger and more likely to be with your code.

@Someprogrammerdude I am not suggesting the problem is with the debugger. I am asking about what tools the debugger has to examine the issue.

You could try to use logging, cProfile. Or you could use VSCode Debugger Without Breakpoints. You could add "justMyCode": false to your launch.json, then you could configure VSCode to break on exceptions automatically.  This allows you to see where the program is when an exception occurs without setting breakpoints.
